# Who can implement inflate in C# for dankogai's javascript deflate?

Tags: c#, javascript, zip

this is dankogai's javascript deflate http://github.com/dankogai/js-deflate
I can't inflate from c#,please help me

Comment: i have tried to using sharpZipLib to decompression ,but it tell me format is format is not correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it, it uses the standard GZip INFLATE/DEFLATE algorithms.

Just a question, why do you need to inflate it outside the browser?

Comment: I need to transfer compress string to the server side,and server side decompression

Answer (score 1):

I found a new one which johan fix something,the dankogai's version I can't inflate using java
https://github.com/johan/js-deflate

If you want to inflate, you must fake zlib head and foot.
Java code is like this:

```
    static public byte[] uncompress(byte[] input) throws DataFormatException {
    int len = input.length;
    byte[] out = new byte[len];
    byte[] src = new byte[len + 6];
    System.arraycopy(input, 0, src, 2, len);
    src[0] = (byte) (120);
    src[1] = (byte) (-100);

    Inflater inflater = new Inflater();
    inflater.setInput(src);

    inflater.finished();
    inflater.inflate(out);
    inflater.reset();

    return out;

}
```

Comment: I updated Johan's code to work with IE, among other things: https://github.com/Mazrick/js-deflate

Answer (score 0):

I use  Google's V8 Javascript engine ( http://javascriptdotnet.codeplex.com/ ) on server side  to run  Javascript code which I run on client side in web browser.